# Need to indentify the app IME are inputing texts into

Tags: android-intent, keyboard, ime

I would like to add a function to my IME to identify the app where it is inputing texts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry, not perfect this question.
But what I found the answer.
Please refer to the following answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

  private LatinKeyboard mCurKeyboard;

  private InputConnection funIc = null;
  private EditorInfo funEi = null;


  @Override 
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);

  }

  @Override 
  public void onInitializeInterface() {
    super.onInitializeInterface();

    mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

    mInputView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    mInputView.invalidate();
  }

 @Override 
  public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

    String pkgname = getWhatisPkgname();

    // other my code..
  }

  // get package name from ime detected application.
  public String getWhatisPkgname() {

    return getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName.toString();

  }
}
```